# Is SSL certificate necessary for MariaDB (or MySQL) to ensure the security

Tags: mysql, database, ssl, mariadb

Does a localhost connection to a MariaDB (or MySQL) database could be intercepted without SSL / TLS protocol.

Comment: To ensure the security of what in what senario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the solution is very simple:
I learned that an unencrypted connection with PHP (MariaDB and MySQL) and the localhost as host will connect via the UNIX socket and is therefore **safe**!
 However, it is not a mistake to use an SSL certificate. This is particularly important for connections via applications in other programming languages ​​(e.g. Java).
 Even if there is an internal danger in the network, it is advisable to choose an encrypted connection. (TLS is even safer then SSLv3).
 
In my case I don't need to use SSL or TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a database server should accept connects only from one application server configured by IP. If the database is used by more then one application, the server, which is able to connect to the database must hold a webservice which can be used to access the database.

There is no need to connect from different servers to a database. So you do not need any secure connection which would slow down the transfer.

Comment: Ok, I only use the Database form my Websites which are also on the same server and they are using `localhost:3306` as host. The database only accept localhost connections. I guess it its **not** necessary to use a SSL connection to transfer the data secure.

Comment: If the database is on the same server as the website and the database is only accepting connections from localhost you definitely do not need a Secure Connection.

Comment: Note that "localhost" as a hostname normally makes the MySQL connector use the UNIX socket, so it does not use TCP. But there are exception cases. For example, Java never uses the local socket connection unless you also use a third-party plugin. Also the Golang connector requires you use the path of the socket file instead of "localhost". So it depends on the language and the connector you use.

Comment: So is it safe with PHP and localhost without SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have concerns about malicious users having access to your network, you should use SSL for connections between the app and the database server.

At my company, everything must be SSL. Every app-to-app connection must be https. Every database connection must be SSL. It doesn't matter that it's behind multiple levels of firewall in our internal network. It's defense in depth.

We do use certificates with the SSL, for both validating the SSL encryption and for authentication. It's stronger authentication than using passwords.

When we say SSL that's because the MySQL options use that term. But we really use TLS.

Note that MySQL's `bind-address` while limiting the clients who can connect to the database server, does not stop wiretappers from intercepting TCP packets. They don't have to connect to the database server to do that, they just have to be on the same network.

Comment: Does that mean it is possible to read the data even if I only accept localhost connection? So nearly the opposite of what @ClausBönnhoff said?

Comment: I think if you have wiretappers in your company (and that should be the only people who have access to your companies network) you have always a big problem.

Comment: Connections on the UNIX socket connection don't go over TCP, so they cannot be sniffed remotely.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, yes, that's true, it would be a big problem if you have malicious agents in your internal network. Do you think that can never happen?

Comment: @BillKarwin that depends on you companies secrets and how you can take afford of grabbing them. But this could be a long discussion and so it’s not the right place here in the comments :)

Comment: Yes, suffice to say that defense in depth is an accepted practice.

Answer (score 1):

SSL (latest version was [SSLv3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/)) is considered to be vulnerable and isn't supported anymore by recent versions of MariaDB (and MySQL).

Instead of use the successor TLS (Transport Layer Security), preferrable protocol versions TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3 which are considered to be safe.
In Addition MariaDB also offers additional security checks for TLS connections, e.g.

Client:

- check the the name in server certificate matches the host name in connection string
- verify the finger print of server certificate
- specify a cipher suite for connection (or exclude certain cipher suites)

Server:

- require X509 certificate from client
- check subject and/or issuer of client certificate.
- specify a cipher suite for connection (or exclude certain cipher suites)

For more information please check

- [Securing connections for client and server](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/).
- [Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)